# Why getToolTipText is never called?

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

I have got a JComponent. The paintComponent method is overridden. I mentioned that tooltips were not occuring reliable. Sometimes they were displayed and sometime they didn't. Now I don't see tooltips anymore on this component. I overwrote getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) to specify the contents of the tooltips. But the methods getToolTipText() and getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) are never called!

What could be wrong here?
What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you will need to call [ToolTipManager.registerComponent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ToolTipManager.html#registerComponent(javax.swing.JComponent)). It's an optimisation, apparently.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to register your component with the tooltip manager.

The default implementation of `setToolTipText()` will do this for you, but if you'd like to override `getToolTipText()` instead, you'll need to add this line somewhere, IE, in your component's constructor:

```
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the tooltip with the method "setToolTipText(String)"?

When the tooltip is not set (or resettet with the value "null"), then the tooltip will not be displayed. (And i suggest the getToolTipText() method will not be called)

This link may help you with this problem: [How To use Tooltips](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html)

(sorry about my english, i think it's not the best,,, ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

First you need to register with the TooltipManager via

```
TooltipManager.registerComponent()
```

Even if that doesent work then

1. Check the value of TooltipManager.getInitialDelay()
2. Check the value of TooltipManager.isEnabled()